# How to create new table from another old table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table from some columns of another old table. Each column in old table has 149 rows but when I create the new table, the resulting table has 1442 rows, which is wrong.

My code:

```
create table newenronss as 
SELECT employeelist.eid
      ,employeelist.firstName
      ,employeelist.lastName
      ,employeelist.Email_id
      ,employeelist.status
      ,message.mid
      ,message.subject
      ,message.body
      ,message.folder
      ,recipientinfo.rid
      ,recipientinfo.rvalue
      ,referenceinfo.reference
FROM  employeelist
INNER JOIN message       ON employeelist.Email_id = message.sender
INNER JOIN recipientinfo ON message.mid = recipientinfo.mid
INNER JOIN referenceinfo ON recipientinfo.rid = referenceinfo.rfid
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: There's nothing in wrong in your code. Perhaps there's a flaw in your logic.

Comment: the information about old table is in : http://www.ahschulz.de/enron-email-data/       .i want to copy some columns of this tables to one new table

Comment: could be that some key is wrong or that match with more that a row.. check join condition  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table_b;
+-----+------+
| id  | a_id |
+-----+------+
| 101 |    1 |
| 102 |    1 |
| 103 |    2 |
| 104 |    4 |
| 105 |    4 |
| 106 |    4 |
| 107 |    4 |
+-----+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table_c;
+------+------+
| id   | a_id |
+------+------+
| 1001 |    2 |
| 1002 |    3 |
| 1003 |    3 |
| 1004 |    4 |
| 1005 |    5 |
| 1006 |    6 |
| 1007 |    7 |
| 1008 |    2 |
| 1009 |    4 |
+------+------+
9 rows in set (0.02 sec)

SELECT *
  FROM table_a a
  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.a_id = a.id
  JOIN table_c c
    ON c.a_id = b.a_id;
+----+-----+------+------+------+
| id | id  | a_id | id   | a_id |
+----+-----+------+------+------+
|  2 | 103 |    2 | 1001 |    2 |
|  4 | 104 |    4 | 1004 |    4 |
|  4 | 105 |    4 | 1004 |    4 |
|  4 | 106 |    4 | 1004 |    4 |
|  4 | 107 |    4 | 1004 |    4 |
|  2 | 103 |    2 | 1008 |    2 |
|  4 | 104 |    4 | 1009 |    4 |
|  4 | 105 |    4 | 1009 |    4 |
|  4 | 106 |    4 | 1009 |    4 |
|  4 | 107 |    4 | 1009 |    4 |
+----+-----+------+------+------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

So, tables a, b, and c have 4 rows, 7 rows, and 9 rows respectively. But when we join them all together we get 10 rows - so there is no obvious correlation between the number of rows in a table and the number of rows in a result.